# Targeting a specific element with knockout js inside of a php foreach loop

Tags: php, knockout.js

I am having trouble figuring out how to expand a specific tbody when I click the chevron in the thead. Their are four tables created by a PHP foreach loop so when I click the chevron all the tbodies are expanded. Everything I have found is related to Knockout's foreach binding which I am not using. Any solution to this problem?
My PHTML

```
<?php foreach($categoryArray as $value): ?>
    <table class="buyback-table" data-bind="scope: 'buyback'">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="3">Category Name</th>
                <th class="text-right"><i type="button" class="fa fa-chevron-down" data-bind="css: { expanded: expand }, click: toggleTable" data-target="#row-<?php echo ++$i; ?>"></i></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="product-table" id="row-<?php echo $i ?>" data-bind="fadeVisible: showTable">
            <tr class="heading">
                <th colspan="2">Product</th>
                <th class="text-right">Buy Price</th>
                <th class="text-right"><span>Sell Price</span></th>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach($productArray as $value): ?>
                <tr class="item-wrapper">
                    <td>img</td>
                    <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
                    <td class="text-right">$0.00</td>
                    <td class="text-right">$1000000.00</td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

My JS:

```
define(['ko'], function(ko) {
    return function() {
        this.showTable = ko.observable(false);
        this.expand = ko.observable(false);

        this.toggleTable = function() {
            this.expand(!this.expand());
            this.showTable(!this.showTable());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The situation you have is that your data is partly embedded in your HTML, courtesy of PHP. If you bind your ViewModel to the entire app, all of the tables is bound to the same ViewModel data items, so of course they will all open and close in sync. You will probably need to find all of the tables and bind a separate ViewModel to each. Better would be to [have Knockout get data from php](http://www.softfinity.com/blog/using-knockout-js-with-php-best-practices/) and use the `foreach` binding.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!